# How to declare a vector of pointers in Cython?

Tags: c++, python, cython

I want to declare something like that:

```
cdef vector[Node*] list2node(list my_list):
```

But Cython gives me this error:

```
cdef vector[Node*] list2node(list my_list):
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

mod.pyx:77:20: Expected an identifier or literal
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `*` -- `vector[Node]` should generate code for a vector of Node pointers.  Using Cython 0.14.1:

```
cdef class Node: 
    pass
cdef vector[Node] list2node():
    pass
cdef vector[int] test_int():
    pass
cdef vector[int*] test_intp(): 
    pass
```

Generates the C++ code:

```
static PyTypeObject *__pyx_ptype_3foo_Node = 0;
static std::vector<struct __pyx_obj_3foo_Node *> __pyx_f_3foo_list2node(void);
static std::vector<int> __pyx_f_3foo_test_int(void);
static std::vector<int *> __pyx_f_3foo_test_intp(void);
```

Comment: how can Node and Node* be the same? im confused

Answer (score 3):

Taking the answer from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13863932/2014591), what you should do is

```
ctypedef Node* Node_ptr
```

and then use `Node_ptr` across your program.

Comment: i like this ctypedef too, making Node confused with Node* is not interesting