# Cython std::pair of two pointers, expected an identifier or literal

Tags: c++, python, pointers, cython

Why in Cython is possible to wrap

```
std::pair<int, Foo*> myPair;
```

but not

```
std::pair<Foo*,Bar*> myPair;
```

In particular, wrapping in Cython the `std::pair` is done as follows:

```
pair[int, Foo*]
```

and works smoothly, but when the first element of is also a pointer I have problems:

```
pair[Foo*,Bar*] myPair2
```

I'm getting

```
pair[Foo*,Bar*] myPair2
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------
test.pyx:50:17: Expected an identifier or literal
```

I'm using Cython 0.17.1, g++ 4.4 on Linux

Comment: The types are treated the same in [the `pair` definition](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/utility.pxd); it is probably a general limitation for the `[]` syntax. You could try to workaround it with a typedef: `ctypedef Foo* Foo_pointer`

Comment: Seems that the ctypedef does the trick, thanks

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You should make that an answer so that it can be accepted :-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The types are treated the same [in the `pair` definition](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/utility.pxd); it is probably a general limitation for the `[]` syntax. You could try to workaround it with a typedef: `ctypedef Foo* Foo_pointer`

*Copy pasted from a comment by @J.F.Sebastian so that this question can be marked as answered (to hopefully clear up the list of unanswered questions -- it has been a month!)*

Comment: So this hits everyone else's google searches faster than my own, this solves the same issue with maps.